# Program to monitor CPU and Memory usage

Tags: centos, monitoring, cpu-usage

I was wondering, if there is a program similar to `time`, but instead of just printing out the time it took to execute the command, it also prints out the average CPU and Memory usage.
Alternatively a program which records the CPU and memory usage every couple of seconds and then writes it to a file would also work.

Any help is appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Sysstat` package is useful. You can customize how often and how many times to harvest
the information. It consists tools for CPU usage , memory , processes. Also can store information in different formats

1. iostat: Reports all statistics about your CPU and I/O statistics for I/O devices.
2. mpstat: Details about CPUs (individual or combined).
3. pidstat: Statistics about running processes/task, CPU, memory etc.
4. sar: Save and report details about different resources (CPU, Memory, IO, Network, kernel etc..).
5. sadc: System activity data collector, used for collecting data in backend for sar.
6. sa1: Fetch and store binary data in sadc data file. This is used with sadc.
7. sa2: Summaries daily report to be used with sar.
8. Sadf: Used for displaying data generated by sar in different formats (CSV or XML).
9. nfsiostat-sysstat: I/O statistics for NFS.
10. cifsiostat: Statistics for CIFS.

Comment: Thanks alot! This looks like what I needed!
Do you know if using this slows down the actual command?

Comment: As every process - will have an impact on the system but in normal case (if you are not on the edge of the resources) it won't affect the performance

Comment: Please, mark as "Answered" if this answered your question